# Trigger to recalculate fields on update

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to write a trigger that collects amounts from other records, and am having trouble with syntax.

I am getting the error:

> CourseSessionTrigger: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.: Trigger.CourseSessionTrigger: line 25, column 1

```
trigger CourseSessionTrigger on Course_Session__c (before insert, before update) {

        String thisId;String room;String facilitator;String resource;String courseStatus;       
        Decimal resourceCost;Decimal roomRate;Decimal facilitatorRate;Decimal totalCost;Decimal sessionLength;Decimal enrollmentCount;
        Datetime startDate;Datetime endDate;

    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
            for (Course_Session__c cs : trigger.new){

            thisId = cs.Id;
            room = cs.Room__c;
            roomRate = cs.Room__r.Hourly_Rate__c;
            facilitator = cs.Faciliator__c;
            facilitatorRate = cs.Faciliator__r.Trainer_Hourly_Rate__c;
            resourceCost = cs.Resource_Cost_PP__c;
            totalCost = cs.Total_Cost__c;

            courseStatus = cs.Course_Status__c;
            startDate = cs.Session_Start__c;
            endDate = cs.Session_End__c;
            sessionLength = cs.Session_Length_hrs__c;
            enrollmentCount = cs.Number_of_Students__c;

            totalCost = (sessionLength * roomRate) + (sessionLength * facilitatorRate) + (enrollmentCount * resourceCost);

            List<Course_Session__c> roomConflicts = [
                SELECT Id FROM Course_Session__c WHERE Session_End__c >= :startDate AND Session_Start__c <= :endDate AND Room__c = :room AND Room__c != NULL AND ID != :thisId];

                IF (!roomConflicts.isEmpty()) { 
                    cs.Conflict_Room__c = TRUE;
                } else {
                    cs.Conflict_Room__c = FALSE;
                }

            List<Course_Session__c> trainerConflicts = [
                SELECT Id FROM Course_Session__c WHERE Session_End__c >= :startDate AND Session_Start__c <= :endDate AND Faciliator__c = :facilitator AND Faciliator__c != NULL AND ID != :thisId];

                IF (!trainerConflicts.isEmpty()) { 
                    cs.Conflict_Facilitator__c = TRUE;
                } else {
                    cs.Conflict_Facilitator__c = FALSE;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that the potential cause could be null values of the fields i am trying to calculate from, and that I need to protect against this, I'm just not too sure how!

Comment: Are you using the Id before record is created? must use After. Also Just noted you got a SELECT inside for loop, might be potential governor limit exception in future.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am unclear with your first point, as it is working to filter and update the current record. As for your second point, to remove the list (SELECT) from the loop, am I to create a map, outside of the trigger.new and then reference the record ids from within the loop?

Comment: Please ignore the 1st point. 2nd, Yes. Better to Avoid SOQL Queries or DML statements inside FOR Loops
An individual Apex request gets a maximum of 100 SOQL queries before exceeding that governor limit. So if this trigger is invoked by a batch of more than 100 Account records, the governor limit will throw a runtime exception.

Comment: Thanks pasan, I knew about the limits, just not where to apply the list or map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 25 in your code is

```
totalCost = (sessionLength * roomRate) + (sessionLength * facilitatorRate) + (enrollmentCount * resourceCost);
```

As you've stated you know, the issue is that one (or possibly more) of those variables is null. Salesforce does not accept null as an argument to a mathematical operator.

While Santanu's answer will avoid the error, his approach is treating the symptoms rather than the cause.

The actual cause of your issues is that you're trying to access *related data* from a trigger context variable (i.e. `cs.Room__r.Hourly_Rate__c` and `cs.Facilitator__r.Trainer_Hourly_Rate__c`). Anything that requires more than one dot/period/full-stop is related data. Trigger context variables do not contain related data. If you try to grab related data from a trigger context variable, you'll get `null` as a result.

If you want that information, you'll need to query for it.

An improved version of your trigger might look like this:

```
trigger CourseSessionTrigger on Course_Session__c (before insert, before update) {

    // You can declare multiple variables of the same type by putting a comma
    //   between the variables (no need to re-type the Type).
    String thisId, room, facilitator, resource, courseStatus;       
    Decimal resourceCost, roomRate, facilitatorRate, totalCost, sessionLength,  enrollmentCount;
    Datetime startDate, endDate;

    // Query the related data that we want to use.
    // We store it in a map using the new Map<keyType, valueType>(<SObject List>)
    //   constructor, which automatically sets the Id of the queried records as
    //   the key of the map (and stores the entire record as the value).
    Map<Id, Course_Session__c> relatedDataMap = new Map<Id, Course_Session__c>([SELECT Id, cs.Room__r.Hourly_Rate__c, cs.Facilitator__r.Trainer_Hourly_Rate__c FROM Coourse_Session__c WHERE Id IN :trigger.new]);

    // Declaring this variable outside of the loop is a small optimization.
    // You don't _need_ to do this, I just do it out of habit these days.
    Course_Session__c relatedData;
    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
                for (Course_Session__c cs : trigger.new){
                relatedData = relatedDataMap.get(cs.Id);

                    thisId = cs.Id;
                    room = cs.Room__c;
                    // Again, this variable holds related data, so we need
                    //   to fetch it from our relatedData variable
                    roomRate = relatedData.Room__r.Hourly_Rate__c;
                    facilitator = cs.Faciliator__c;
                    // Same deal with this variable
                    facilitatorRate = relatedData.Faciliator__r.Trainer_Hourly_Rate__c;
                    resourceCost = cs.Resource_Cost_PP__c;
                    totalCost = cs.Total_Cost__c;

                    courseStatus = cs.Course_Status__c;
                    startDate = cs.Session_Start__c;
                    endDate = cs.Session_End__c;
                    sessionLength = cs.Session_Length_hrs__c;
                    enrollmentCount = cs.Number_of_Students__c;

                    totalCost = (sessionLength * roomRate) + (sessionLength * facilitatorRate) + (enrollmentCount * resourceCost);

                // other code omitted
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, even with this, it's possible to still run into null values. One more improvement would be to test individual fields for null values, and give them some default value (usually 0) if they are null.

You could do that with an if/else statement, but the ternary logic operator `<test>? <value if true>:<value if false>` is equivalent, and can require less typing

```
resourceCost = cs.Resource_Cost_PP__c;
if(resourceCost == null){
    resourceCost = 0 ;
}

// or, alternatively
resourceCost = cs.Resource_Cost_PP__c == null ? 0 : cs.Resource_Cost_PP__c;
```

Applying that to your trigger...

```
trigger CourseSessionTrigger on Course_Session__c (before insert, before update) {

    // You can declare multiple variables of the same type by putting a comma
    //   between the variables (no need to re-type the Type).
    String thisId, room, facilitator, resource, courseStatus;       
    Decimal resourceCost, roomRate, facilitatorRate, totalCost, sessionLength,  enrollmentCount;
    Datetime startDate, endDate;

    // Query the related data that we want to use.
    // We store it in a map using the new Map<keyType, valueType>(<SObject List>)
    //   constructor, which automatically sets the Id of the queried records as
    //   the key of the map (and stores the entire record as the value).
    Map<Id, Course_Session__c> relatedDataMap = new Map<Id, Course_Session__c>([SELECT Id, cs.Room__r.Hourly_Rate__c, cs.Facilitator__r.Trainer_Hourly_Rate__c FROM Coourse_Session__c WHERE Id IN :trigger.new]);

    // Declaring this variable outside of the loop is a small optimization.
    // You don't _need_ to do this, I just do it out of habit these days.
    Course_Session__c relatedData;
    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
                for (Course_Session__c cs : trigger.new){
                relatedData = relatedDataMap.get(cs.Id);

                    thisId = cs.Id;
                    room = cs.Room__c;
                    // Again, this variable holds related data, so we need
                    //   to fetch it from our relatedData variable
                    roomRate = relatedData.Room__r.Hourly_Rate__c == null ? 0 : relatedData.Room__r.Hourly_Rate__c;
                    facilitator = cs.Faciliator__c;
                    // Same deal with this variable
                    facilitatorRate = relatedData.Faciliator__r.Trainer_Hourly_Rate__c == null ? 0 : relatedData.Faciliator__r.Trainer_Hourly_Rate__c;
                    resourceCost = cs.Resource_Cost_PP__c == null ? 0 : cs.Resource_Cost_PP__c;
                    totalCost = cs.Total_Cost__c == null ? 0 : cs.Total_Cost__c;

                    courseStatus = cs.Course_Status__c;
                    startDate = cs.Session_Start__c;
                    endDate = cs.Session_End__c;
                    sessionLength = cs.Session_Length_hrs__c == null ? 0 : cs.Session_Length_hrs__c;
                    enrollmentCount = cs.Number_of_Students__c;

                    totalCost = (sessionLength * roomRate) + (sessionLength * facilitatorRate) + (enrollmentCount * resourceCost);

                // other code omitted
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That said and done, this is the type of calculation that I would do via formula field (rather than a trigger). It's simple enough, and related data can be pulled into a formula  (uses the same `lookupFieldName__r.Field` syntax that you'd use in a trigger or other Apex). The big advantages to using a formula field here are that:

- Formula fields can be set to automatically handle nulls (treat blank values as zeroes)
- No code (and thus, no deployment) is required
- Because no code is required, a unit test is not required either

Comment: As a final note, and as others have noted, queries inside of loops are bad. I would suggest working on moving that outside of your loop after you finish resolving the NPE. If you need help on doing that (removing the query from your loop), that would be worthy of another question (but try to search for similar questions first).

Comment: Thanks Derek, great response! I had come to the related records null issue after my original post, and overcame it by using formula fields to pull the data to the current record, and using those instead. As for why a trigger - I have this object looking and down parent/child, with roll up summaries which formulas don't play nicely with. Very useful post indeed!

Answer (score 2):

You should put a `null` checking before executing specified line

```
if(sessionLength !=null && roomRate != null && facilitatorRate !=null && enrollmentCount !=null && resourceCost != null)
        {
            totalCost = (sessionLength * roomRate) + (sessionLength * facilitatorRate) + (enrollmentCount * resourceCost);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Santanu, the Null error has been fixed. Unfortunately the total cost isn't being updated...

Comment: you need to refactor your code to eliminate query inside for loop. If you face any issues then post as a separate question

Comment: I've downvoted this answer because while it does prevent the error OP is having, this approach merely _avoids_ the issue rather than _solving_ the root cause.

Comment: @SantanuBoral Although this answer helped me understand the issue, Derek's answer below is more useful to others (and of course myself). Thanks for the help though!